# How to retrive Compile Sources menu in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am develop an app. but by mistake i delete the Compile Source Menu from Build Phase

see the image ther is no Compile Source Menu. I search lots of in the google but can't find the answer. please tell me how to show this menu..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your menu bar on top of the screen, choose the `Editor` menu. Here you'll find an `Add Build Phase` menu item where you can add any build phase (again) to your project.

Answer (score -1):

**added main.m and yourclassess .m file into the compile source after below did**

It's very similar:

1. Select the project in the project navigator.
2. Select the Target in the detail view.
3. Select the Build Phase tab.
4. Expand the Compiled Sources section
5. Remove the file you don't want to be compiled
   anymore

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD follow above the procedure in xcode menu you get compile source